# How to change GitHub SSH key email address

Tags: email, github, ssh, ssh-keys

When generating an SSH key, the GitHub Docs says to replace your_email@example.com with your GitHub email.

> `$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"`

I've already set up everything a while ago, but i noticed the email i put is wrong, and want to edit it now.

I read somewhere that it's not a huge deal and that the email there will not affect anything, but i still prefer changing it. I haven't found an answer for this so far.

Is it possible to do that? If so then how?

Answer (score 2):

The `-C` flag means "comment".  In other words, this is a comment, with the sole purpose of helping the user determine the purpose for the key.  (Mine, for example, says "bmc@camp", which are the username and hostname in use when it was created, which is the default behaviour.)  It can be almost anything you like and is solely for your benefit.

You can edit it by simply modifying `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` (or `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or whatever file your public key is in).  It's simply the string at the end of the line.

I don't believe GitHub actually stores the comment anywhere.  When you look at your public keys on GitHub, such as with a URL like https://github.com/bk2204.keys, it doesn't appear there.  If it appears in the settings and you'd like to correct it, you can remove the key and re-add it, changing the description as you like.  The description defaults to the comment, I believe, if one is not specified, but you can override it.